# How do I get the validation to work?

Tags: php, jquery, database

I have been reading tutorials but still can't see what I am doing wrong. This should be a simple feedback form that inputs the author, email, comment and timestamp into a database.

Here's the feedback form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Feedback</title>

  <style type="text/css">
  fieldset{float:center; width:50%; padding:6px;}
  label{float:left; width:10%; font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:5px}
  textarea{font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
  input{margin-bottom:5px;}
  div#sent{display:none; font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
 <div id="sent">Thank You we appreciate your comments</div>

<div id="form" align="center">
<form id="feedback" action="#">
<fieldset>
     <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <label>email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <label>Comment:</label><br />
    <textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea><br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></>
 </script> <script type = "text/javascript">

 $(function(){ 
          var expressions = {
            name:/^[a-z]+[\.-']|\s)?[a-z]+$/i,
            email:/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/,
            comment:/^\w+/
           };

$('form#feedback').submit(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault(); 
             var valid=true;
                 for(var i=0; i<this.elements.length; i++){
                 var field= this.elements[i];
                if(field.type=='text'||field.type=='textarea'){
                 if(!expressions[field.name].test($(field).val())){
             alert('Oops! Mistake in '+field.name.replace('_',' ').toUpperCase()+'.');

                 field.focus();
                 valid=false;
                 return false;
                    }
                 }
         }

   If(valid){
             $.post('enter.php'; $(this).serialise(), function(data){
                                                    if(data.sucess{
                        $(div#form).fadeOut();
                        $(div#sent).fadeIn();
                           }else{
                               alert('We had a problem submitting the page');
                           }
              }, 'json');
                        return false;                                       }
                         });
         });
        </script>
 </body>                           
 </html>
```

and here is the processing code:

```
    $remove= array('submit','reset');
    $accepted= array('name','email', 'comment');


    foreach($data as $field=> $value){
        if(in_array($field,$remove)){
        unset($data[$field]);
            } elseif (!in_array($field, $accepted)){
          header('Location:feedback.php');
    }
    }
      $expressions = array(   
          name=>"~^[a-z]+[\.-']|\s)?[a-z]+$~i",
          email=>'~^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$~',
          comment=>'~^\w+~'
             );

      foreach($data as $field=> $value){
            if(!preg_match($expressions[$field], $value)) {
            header('Location: feedback.php');
                    }
        }

      require_once('connections\connect2.php');

              $response =(object) null;
              $Stmt= $db->stmt_init();
              $query='INSERT INTO feedback(name, email, comment, submitted) 
              VALUES(?,?,?,NOW())';

              if($Stmt->prepare($query)){
                  $Stmt-> bind_param('sss',
                                      $data['name'],
                                      $data['email'],
                                      $data['comment']);
                  $response->success=$stmt->execute();
              }else {
                  $response-> false;
              }
              echo json_encode($response);
              ?>
```

Can anyone see why this is not working? The form does not submit, nothing goes into the database, no messages/change to the form once fillled when submit is clicked.

Comment: **For "one" thing**, you INSERT 4 values, but you're binding 3. I can't say for the rest of your code, but that will get you started to debug it. You're also using `$Stmt` and `$stmt->execute()` **another brick wall.**

Comment: Thanks - fixed those but my form is still not submitting. Is there a problem in the first set of code? -Merran

Comment: You're welcome. It's hard to say where the other errors actually may lie.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you need to check.

- remove  e.preventDefault();  this is preventing your form from being submitted.
- this.elements.length will return name, email, text, submit, reset while you have validator expression for only name, email and comment. which means that you need to change this.elements to some other values which picks only the fields that need validation not the submit, reset button.